# Transforming only part of the NA's of a variable in 0

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working in a dataframe in RStudio trying to understand if there is a correlation between doing exercises and the general health of the person. There is three main variables:

exerof1: this variable is related to how many of times the people in the research exercised in the last 30 days.

exerany2: in this variable, the participants responded if they practiced exercises in the last month, therefore they can say yes, no or refuse to answer.

genhlth: a factor variable which split the observations in 5 levels.

I have already transformed the exeroft1 variable, but 30% of this variable are NA's and most of them are NA's because they answered "No" in the "exerany2" question.

My objective is to identificate the people who said "No" in the "exerany" variable and are listed in the exerof1 as "NAs" to transform those "NAs" in 0.

I don't know if my analysis is the best way because I am a beginner. I tried to do what I want using ifelse, but I am struggling. I also tried to check if there is another thread with the same question, but I coundn't find.

I will await for your feedback.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve] ... **then edit your question!** What have you tried so far?

Comment: As your question is more about which analysis rather than how to program it, it is probably better suited for getting some stats advice. I have voted to move ot to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @user20650 I believe there is the part of how to perform the `NA` imputation in `R`, that goes into stackoverflow.com. And then there are some doubts about when to impute `NA` with `0`, that I would say that is very context dependent and not sure if that is a statistical question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is called `data`:

```
data[(is.na(data$exerof1) & data$exerany2=="No"),"exerof1"] <- 0
```

Basically we select the rows the satisfy your condition, then pick the column `exerof1`, and asign those the value `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have made some changes in the code to be able to work it with dplyr library and because of that, I was able to reach my goal. Also, I would like to emphasize that I will study more about how to do a proper question to don't commit the same mistakes again.